# Jquerymobile programmatically reload page without duplicating page in DOM

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an annoying issue, I want to reload the page I am on programmatically, whilst maintaining a page transition, but I don't want to double it up in the DOM!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your relevant code? What function do you use?

You are aware of the properties of `changePage`?

```
$.mobile.changePage("#pageId", { allowSamePageTransition : true, reloadPage: true } );
```

Otherwise you can always remove the previous page yourself

```
$('#pageId').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
  $(ui.prevPage).remove();
});
```